# For a 3d CAD program, should I remove my use of Vertex Arrays/Display lists in favor of Vertex buffer objects?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I think I am going to make an attempt at removing display lists from my implementation and put in Vertex Arrays.  I know Vertex Buffer Objects are more efficient, however Vertex Arrays have been around since openGL 1.1 and as such function in almost every environment I believe. How is compatibility for vertex buffer objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertex Buffer Objects are essentially Vertex Arrays, where instead of pointing to a address in your program's process address space, OpenGL gives you a handle to OpenGL managed memory and the Vertex Array pointers are offsets into the memory given out by that handle.

It is actually very easy to add VBO support to programs that already make use of Vertex Arrays. It's as easy to conditionally use VBOs if they are available and fall back to client addess space Vertex Arrays if not.

Comment: @dah: Just look up any tutorial about VBOs. If you're familiar with Vertex Arrays you'll see, that most of it you should be familar, and the only additional twist added are calls to glGenBuffers, glBindBuffer and glBufferData, as well as that the pointers given to glVertexPointer no longer point to memory in your program, but are offsets into the data uploaded with glBufferData.